# Crossing the Lao/Thai border at Ban Than - no border office?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, thailand, borders, laos, land-borders

My brother and I are biking from Luang Prabang to Chiang Mai  just realized our bike route takes us through a border crossing with no immigration office. Is this a problem? I know we can do 15 days visa exemption but does this still require crossing through an immigration office?

Comment: Could you clarify the name of the border? Google fails to find any mentions of a "Ban Than" border crossing.

Comment: Ban Than is quite some distance from the border. Going from Luang Prabang through Ban Than and further to Chiang Mai, it would make sense to cross the border at the Bang Pangmon - Wat Huak crossing, but there you will of course find an immigration office. Can you please clarify your question? As asked, it does not really make sense.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a map or map link so we can see exactly which route you're on. There's a good chance it's a border crossing only Thais and Laos are allowed to use. I tried to cross from Cambodia to Vietnam at such a crossing a few months ago. And was turned back. There's also a chance we're overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks guys. My question seems to have been fully significant. I was having a hard time loading the map to see the small border towns. However, I did find a more recent account: http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/route-planning/ban-huak-phayao-thai-laos-76269 That said, this was just before the most recent coup I'm may 27th 2014. So who knows if that border crossing was closed again.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes here. This is a very common type of question I've asked myself here several times.

Answer (score 14):

If this is the border crossing I'm looking at on Google Maps right now, it looks like it does indeed have an office. The town on the Lao side is **Ban Pangmong** while on the Thai side is **Ban Huak** on **Route 1093**. No visible signs in English would seem to suggest a negative but notice the photo is from **January 2013**:
[image: Google Maps Street View of the office]

> [Link to Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@19.678769,100.4261224,3a,54.4y,19.48h,88.13t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sreRD_8CYDlFXvzl68lAR8Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1)

But I finally found [a recent-ish thread on a site for motorcyclists in Asia](http://www.rideasia.net/motorcycle-forum/showthread.php?t=1340&p=51626&viewfull=1#post51626) from **February 2012**. The earlier post states that indeed only locals (Laos and Thais) can cross here, seemingly only open twice per month for a local market. A post ater in the thread from **February 2015** seems to suggest nothing has changed but doesn't actually say whether the person has check recently. Compare this with [Sebrand's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/56130/140). The update here may well be an assumption.

Answer (score 12):

You can ONLY enter Thailand at an international border crossing.

If you cross anywhere else you will be in Thailand illegally.  When you try to depart you will likely be arrested, charged and deported, not the kind of thing you wanted noted in your passport.

The fact that you qualify for a 15 day visa waiver entry does not allow you to bypass entry formalities, Immigration still has to grant you permission to enter and stamp that entry in your passport.

And because at least one of the people involved in the recent Bangkok bombing crossed the border illegally, Thai Immigration and border control is currently much stricter than before with enforcement.

I would change your route and head for an open international border crossing such as Huay Xai - Chiang Khong or Muang Ngeun - Huay Kon.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys. My question seems to have been fully significant. I was having a hard time loading the map to see the small border towns. However, I did find [this more recent account](http://www.horizonsunlimited.com/hubb/route-planning/ban-huak-phayao-thai-laos-76269) from 15 May 2014:

> The new Ban Huak / Phayao Border crossing (19.679285, 100.430435) - opened in 2013 as a trade border only; is now open to foreigners.
>   I could find no information regarding foreigners crossing this border online so I took a chance on my ride to Chiang Rai which paid off and crossed from Laos to Thailand this week.
>   It is a much more direct route from Luang Prabang, Laos than the Chiang Khong Friendship bridge and was a quick and easy crossing with not much traffic.
>   I crossed on a big bike with Carnet de passage and obtained my Thai visa on arrival. Visa on arrival facility is also available on the Laos side.

That said, this was just before the most recent coup I'm may 27th 2014. So who knows if that border crossing was closed again.

Comment: The post at the link does clearly say that it was open to foreigners with visa on arrival in both directions a year and a bit ago. So this does provide an answer, only if you follow the link though. But yeah the more recent post I found makes it seem that it's no longer open to foreigners. So perhaps neither is conclusive.